# Can I use Laravel's eloquent hasManyThrough relationship for my specific case?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5, laravel-5.4, eloquent

I'm trying to retrieve data from a table that I don't have a direct relationship with from the model I am currently using.

My data structure:

Table: **posts**

- id - integer
- title - string

---

Table: **post_stacks**

- id - integer
- post_id - integer
- stack_id - integer

---

Table: **stacks**

- id - integer
- body - string
- url - string

---

My eloquent model is from the Post.php (posts table) and i'm trying to get all the stacks associated to my post (from the stacks table). I want to declare my relationships only on Post.php and not my pivot table (post_stacks). I tried using hasManyThrough but i can't get it to work?

```
public function img()
    {
        return $this->hasManyThrough(\App\Stack::class, \App\PostStack::class, 'post_id', 'stack_id', 'id');
    }
```

Would anyone know how i can retrieve my desired data? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you try to put below relationships on your posts model.

```
public function stacks()
{
    return $this->hasManyThrough(
        'App\Stacks', 'App\PostStacks',
        'post_id', 'id', 'id'
    );
}
```

Also have a look at this, https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#has-many-through

According to this doc, The third argument in `hasManyThrough` is the name of the foreign key on the intermediate model. In our case `'post_id'` is the foreign key on `post_stack` that has direct relation to `posts`.

Fourth argument is the name of the foreign key on the final model. ie, `'id'` on `stacks`. that has relationship to `post_stacks` `( 'post_id' )`. Fifth argument is the local key. ie, `id` of posts